# GitHub API в Java

Tags: github, java

Я знаю,  что `GitHub` используется для отслеживания версий проекта.  Как им пользоваться?  И можно ли сделать так чтобы, к примеру,  я написал код на java, загрузил его в свой репозиторий, и у клиента выполняется этот код выполняется?  Если можно,  то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub - это хостинг
Git - это система управления версиями
Jenkins - это инструмент, для непрерывной интеграции

тебе надо:

1. установить git и приблизительно научится им пользоваться
2. выбрать сервер для хранения кода, это может быть github, но он платный для приватных проектов (есть много хороших бесплатных аналогов)
3. попробовать разобраться с jenkins - с его помощью можно "выполнять код у клиента", делать билды по разписанию, гонять тесты

Comment: Можно поподробнее о бесплатных аналогах?

Comment: xp-dev.com, assembla.com, bitbucket.org